# Issue uploading Lua code to nodemcu on ESP32 due to missing file.open()

Tags: lua, nodemcu

I'm trying to run nodemcu on an ESP32 (more memory than esp8266). I've build the firmware using the sources from https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware.git, the dev-esp32 branch. The build was done on a windows/WSL2/Ubuntu system.

The firmware works, however I am having issues with uploading and saving lua files. I've tried various tools, for example http://chilipeppr.com/esp32.

Functions like 'Heap' and 'Reset' work fine. However, uploading files fails. The console output is:

```
file.open("unnamed1.lua", "w")
 file.writeline([[print("Test")]])
 file.writeline([[]])
 file.close()
 node.compile("unnamed1.lua")
> file.open("unnamed1.lua", "w")
Lua error:  stdin:1: attempt to call field 'open' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
    [C]: ?
> file.writeline([[print("Test")]])
Lua error:  stdin:1: attempt to call field 'writeline' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
    [C]: ?
> file.writeline([[]])
Lua error:  stdin:1: attempt to call field 'writeline' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
    [C]: ?
> file.close()
Lua error:  stdin:1: attempt to call field 'close' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
    [C]: ?
> node.compile("unnamed1.lua")
Lua error:  stdin:1: cannot open unnamed1.lua: No such file or directory
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'compile'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
    [C]: ?
```

Apparently, ESP8266 nodemcu implements file.open() where ESP32 nodemcu doesn't (ESP32 seems to implement the Lua io lib instead).

Am I having a build issue? I don't think so as https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev-esp32/modules/file/ doesn't list file.open()

Is there an issue with the upload tools failing to detect my ESP32? Upon reset, my firmware reports as:
'''
NodeMCU ESP32 build unspecified powered by Lua 5.1.4 [5.1-doublefp] on IDF v4.4.3
'''

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try `io` lib instead.

```
do
    local file = io.open("unnamed1.lua", "w")
    file:write[[
        print("Test")
    ]]
    file:close()
end
node.compile("unnamed1.lua")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to upload files to the ESP32 using the io-module use this branch of nodeMCU-Tools..[serg3295 NodeMCU-Tool](https://github.com/serg3295/NodeMCU-Tool/tree/dev-esp32)

It took me hours of searching to find this. Its a command line tool, so not as easy to use as Chillipeppr or ESPlorer.

Answer (score 0):

There is VS Code extension [NodeMCU-Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=boressoft.nodemcu-tools) (marketplace.visualstudio.com). You can use it instead of ESPlorer.